# iOS/Xcode Issue: Duplicating Results on First In-App Purchase and Freezing App on Second Attempt

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova

Dear StackOverflow Community,

I'm encountering a perplexing issue with my iOS app that involves In-App Purchase functionality. Despite thorough examination of the code, including a snippet provided below, there don't appear to be any obvious flaws. However, when users attempt their first In-App Purchase, the result duplicates inexplicably. Moreover, upon the second attempt, the app freezes unexpectedly.

The app was developed using GDevelop and subsequently ported through Cordova utilizing the Cordova-plugin-purchase plugin for In-App Purchases. Despite rigorous testing and code reviews, the root cause of this issue remains elusive.

Here's a snippet of the log and code for reference:

JC Code functionalities:

1- Register Item:

```
if (typeof gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__RegisterItem !== "undefined") {
  gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__RegisterItem.registeredGdjsCallbacks.forEach(callback =>
    gdjs._unregisterCallback(callback)
  );
}

gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__RegisterItem = {};


gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__RegisterItem.userFunc0x88cab8 = function GDJSInlineCode(runtimeScene, eventsFunctionContext) {
"use strict";
if(!window.CdvPurchase || !window.CdvPurchase.store) return;
const store = window.CdvPurchase.store;
store.register({
    id: eventsFunctionContext.getArgument("id"),
    type: eventsFunctionContext.getArgument("type"),
    platform: eventsFunctionContext.getArgument("platform"),
});

};
gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__RegisterItem.eventsList0 = function(runtimeScene, eventsFunctionContext) {

{


gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__RegisterItem.userFunc0x88cab8(runtimeScene, typeof eventsFunctionContext !== 'undefined' ? eventsFunctionContext : undefined);

}


};

gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__RegisterItem.func = function(runtimeScene, id, type, platform, parentEventsFunctionContext) {
var eventsFunctionContext = {
  _objectsMap: {
},
  _objectArraysMap: {
},
  _behaviorNamesMap: {
},
  getObjects: function(objectName) {
    return eventsFunctionContext._objectArraysMap[objectName] || [];
  },
  getObjectsLists: function(objectName) {
    return eventsFunctionContext._objectsMap[objectName] || null;
  },
  getBehaviorName: function(behaviorName) {
    return eventsFunctionContext._behaviorNamesMap[behaviorName] || behaviorName;
  },
  createObject: function(objectName) {
    const objectsList = eventsFunctionContext._objectsMap[objectName];
    if (objectsList) {
      const object = parentEventsFunctionContext ?
        parentEventsFunctionContext.createObject(objectsList.firstKey()) :
        runtimeScene.createObject(objectsList.firstKey());
      if (object) {
        objectsList.get(objectsList.firstKey()).push(object);
        eventsFunctionContext._objectArraysMap[objectName].push(object);
      }
      return object;    }
    return null;
  },
  getInstancesCountOnScene: function(objectName) {
    const objectsList = eventsFunctionContext._objectsMap[objectName];
    let count = 0;
    if (objectsList) {
      for(const objectName in objectsList.items)
        count += parentEventsFunctionContext ?
parentEventsFunctionContext.getInstancesCountOnScene(objectName) :
        runtimeScene.getInstancesCountOnScene(objectName);
    }
    return count;
  },
  getLayer: function(layerName) {
    return runtimeScene.getLayer(layerName);
  },
  getArgument: function(argName) {
if (argName === "id") return id;
if (argName === "type") return type;
if (argName === "platform") return platform;
    return "";
  },
  getOnceTriggers: function() { return runtimeScene.getOnceTriggers(); }
};


gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__RegisterItem.eventsList0(runtimeScene, eventsFunctionContext);

return;
}

gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__RegisterItem.registeredGdjsCallbacks = [];
```

2- Finalize registration:

```
if (typeof gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__FinalizeRegistration !== "undefined") {
  gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__FinalizeRegistration.registeredGdjsCallbacks.forEach(callback =>
    gdjs._unregisterCallback(callback)
  );
}

gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__FinalizeRegistration = {};


gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__FinalizeRegistration.userFunc0x893120 = function GDJSInlineCode(runtimeScene, eventsFunctionContext) {
"use strict";
if(!window.CdvPurchase || !window.CdvPurchase.store) return;
const store = window.CdvPurchase.store;

store.initialize();
store.update();
store.ready(() => {
    console.info('IAP store is ready!')
    const variable = runtimeScene.getVariables().get("IAP_STORE_READY");
    variable.setBoolean(true);
})

};
gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__FinalizeRegistration.eventsList0 = function(runtimeScene, eventsFunctionContext) {

{


gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__FinalizeRegistration.userFunc0x893120(runtimeScene, typeof eventsFunctionContext !== 'undefined' ? eventsFunctionContext : undefined);

}


};

gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__FinalizeRegistration.func = function(runtimeScene, parentEventsFunctionContext) {
var eventsFunctionContext = {
  _objectsMap: {
},
  _objectArraysMap: {
},
  _behaviorNamesMap: {
},
  getObjects: function(objectName) {
    return eventsFunctionContext._objectArraysMap[objectName] || [];
  },
  getObjectsLists: function(objectName) {
    return eventsFunctionContext._objectsMap[objectName] || null;
  },
  getBehaviorName: function(behaviorName) {
    return eventsFunctionContext._behaviorNamesMap[behaviorName] || behaviorName;
  },
  createObject: function(objectName) {
    const objectsList = eventsFunctionContext._objectsMap[objectName];
    if (objectsList) {
      const object = parentEventsFunctionContext ?
        parentEventsFunctionContext.createObject(objectsList.firstKey()) :
        runtimeScene.createObject(objectsList.firstKey());
      if (object) {
        objectsList.get(objectsList.firstKey()).push(object);
        eventsFunctionContext._objectArraysMap[objectName].push(object);
      }
      return object;    }
    return null;
  },
  getInstancesCountOnScene: function(objectName) {
    const objectsList = eventsFunctionContext._objectsMap[objectName];
    let count = 0;
    if (objectsList) {
      for(const objectName in objectsList.items)
        count += parentEventsFunctionContext ?
parentEventsFunctionContext.getInstancesCountOnScene(objectName) :
        runtimeScene.getInstancesCountOnScene(objectName);
    }
    return count;
  },
  getLayer: function(layerName) {
    return runtimeScene.getLayer(layerName);
  },
  getArgument: function(argName) {
    return "";
  },
  getOnceTriggers: function() { return runtimeScene.getOnceTriggers(); }
};


gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__FinalizeRegistration.eventsList0(runtimeScene, eventsFunctionContext);

return;
}

gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__FinalizeRegistration.registeredGdjsCallbacks = [];
```

3- Store is ready:

```
if (typeof gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__StoreReady !== "undefined") {
  gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__StoreReady.registeredGdjsCallbacks.forEach(callback =>
    gdjs._unregisterCallback(callback)
  );
}

gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__StoreReady = {};


gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__StoreReady.userFunc0x7b70e0 = function GDJSInlineCode(runtimeScene, eventsFunctionContext) {
"use strict";
const variable = runtimeScene.getVariables().get("IAP_STORE_READY");

eventsFunctionContext.returnValue = variable.getAsBoolean() === true;

};
gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__StoreReady.eventsList0 = function(runtimeScene, eventsFunctionContext) {

{


gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__StoreReady.userFunc0x7b70e0(runtimeScene, typeof eventsFunctionContext !== 'undefined' ? eventsFunctionContext : undefined);

}


};

gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__StoreReady.func = function(runtimeScene, parentEventsFunctionContext) {
var eventsFunctionContext = {
  _objectsMap: {
},
  _objectArraysMap: {
},
  _behaviorNamesMap: {
},
  getObjects: function(objectName) {
    return eventsFunctionContext._objectArraysMap[objectName] || [];
  },
  getObjectsLists: function(objectName) {
    return eventsFunctionContext._objectsMap[objectName] || null;
  },
  getBehaviorName: function(behaviorName) {
    return eventsFunctionContext._behaviorNamesMap[behaviorName] || behaviorName;
  },
  createObject: function(objectName) {
    const objectsList = eventsFunctionContext._objectsMap[objectName];
    if (objectsList) {
      const object = parentEventsFunctionContext ?
        parentEventsFunctionContext.createObject(objectsList.firstKey()) :
        runtimeScene.createObject(objectsList.firstKey());
      if (object) {
        objectsList.get(objectsList.firstKey()).push(object);
        eventsFunctionContext._objectArraysMap[objectName].push(object);
      }
      return object;    }
    return null;
  },
  getInstancesCountOnScene: function(objectName) {
    const objectsList = eventsFunctionContext._objectsMap[objectName];
    let count = 0;
    if (objectsList) {
      for(const objectName in objectsList.items)
        count += parentEventsFunctionContext ?
parentEventsFunctionContext.getInstancesCountOnScene(objectName) :
        runtimeScene.getInstancesCountOnScene(objectName);
    }
    return count;
  },
  getLayer: function(layerName) {
    return runtimeScene.getLayer(layerName);
  },
  getArgument: function(argName) {
    return "";
  },
  getOnceTriggers: function() { return runtimeScene.getOnceTriggers(); }
};


gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__StoreReady.eventsList0(runtimeScene, eventsFunctionContext);

return !!eventsFunctionContext.returnValue;
}

gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__StoreReady.registeredGdjsCallbacks = [];
```

4- Watch event:

```
if (typeof gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__WatchItemEvent !== "undefined") {
  gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__WatchItemEvent.registeredGdjsCallbacks.forEach(callback =>
    gdjs._unregisterCallback(callback)
  );
}

gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__WatchItemEvent = {};


gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__WatchItemEvent.userFunc0x7b70e0 = function GDJSInlineCode(runtimeScene, eventsFunctionContext) {
"use strict";
if(!window.CdvPurchase || !window.CdvPurchase.store) return;
const store = window.CdvPurchase.store;

const eventName = eventsFunctionContext.getArgument("event");
const productId = eventsFunctionContext.getArgument("id");

const transactionCallback = (transaction) => {
    const products = transaction.products;
    // If the product being watched is in the list of products in the transaction, save into a variable.
    if (products.find(transactionProduct => transactionProduct.id === productId)) {
        const variable = runtimeScene.getVariables().get(eventsFunctionContext.getArgument("variableName"));
        variable.setBoolean(true);
    }
}

store.when().approved((transaction) => {
    // If we're watching this event, call the callback.
    if (eventName === 'approved') {
        transactionCallback(transaction);
    }
    // Automatically verify the transaction on approved.
    transaction.verify();
})

// Automatically finish a receipt when verified.
store.when().verified(receipt => receipt.finish())

store.when().finished((transaction) => {
    // If we're watching this event, call the callback.
    if (eventName === 'finished') {
        transactionCallback(transaction);
    }
    // Nothing left to do when finished.
})

};
gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__WatchItemEvent.eventsList0 = function(runtimeScene, eventsFunctionContext) {

{


gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__WatchItemEvent.userFunc0x7b70e0(runtimeScene, typeof eventsFunctionContext !== 'undefined' ? eventsFunctionContext : undefined);

}


};

gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__WatchItemEvent.func = function(runtimeScene, id, variableName, event, parentEventsFunctionContext) {
var eventsFunctionContext = {
  _objectsMap: {
},
  _objectArraysMap: {
},
  _behaviorNamesMap: {
},
  getObjects: function(objectName) {
    return eventsFunctionContext._objectArraysMap[objectName] || [];
  },
  getObjectsLists: function(objectName) {
    return eventsFunctionContext._objectsMap[objectName] || null;
  },
  getBehaviorName: function(behaviorName) {
    return eventsFunctionContext._behaviorNamesMap[behaviorName] || behaviorName;
  },
  createObject: function(objectName) {
    const objectsList = eventsFunctionContext._objectsMap[objectName];
    if (objectsList) {
      const object = parentEventsFunctionContext ?
        parentEventsFunctionContext.createObject(objectsList.firstKey()) :
        runtimeScene.createObject(objectsList.firstKey());
      if (object) {
        objectsList.get(objectsList.firstKey()).push(object);
        eventsFunctionContext._objectArraysMap[objectName].push(object);
      }
      return object;    }
    return null;
  },
  getInstancesCountOnScene: function(objectName) {
    const objectsList = eventsFunctionContext._objectsMap[objectName];
    let count = 0;
    if (objectsList) {
      for(const objectName in objectsList.items)
        count += parentEventsFunctionContext ?
parentEventsFunctionContext.getInstancesCountOnScene(objectName) :
        runtimeScene.getInstancesCountOnScene(objectName);
    }
    return count;
  },
  getLayer: function(layerName) {
    return runtimeScene.getLayer(layerName);
  },
  getArgument: function(argName) {
if (argName === "id") return id;
if (argName === "variableName") return variableName;
if (argName === "event") return event;
    return "";
  },
  getOnceTriggers: function() { return runtimeScene.getOnceTriggers(); }
};


gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__WatchItemEvent.eventsList0(runtimeScene, eventsFunctionContext);

return;
}

gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__WatchItemEvent.registeredGdjsCallbacks = [];
```

5- Order Item:

```
if (typeof gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__OrderItem !== "undefined") {
  gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__OrderItem.registeredGdjsCallbacks.forEach(callback =>
    gdjs._unregisterCallback(callback)
  );
}

gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__OrderItem = {};


gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__OrderItem.userFunc0x7b70e0 = function GDJSInlineCode(runtimeScene, eventsFunctionContext) {
"use strict";
if(!window.CdvPurchase || !window.CdvPurchase.store) return;
const store = window.CdvPurchase.store;

const product = store.get(eventsFunctionContext.getArgument("id"));
const offer = product.getOffer();
offer.order();

};
gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__OrderItem.eventsList0 = function(runtimeScene, eventsFunctionContext) {

{


gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__OrderItem.userFunc0x7b70e0(runtimeScene, typeof eventsFunctionContext !== 'undefined' ? eventsFunctionContext : undefined);

}


};

gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__OrderItem.func = function(runtimeScene, id, parentEventsFunctionContext) {
var eventsFunctionContext = {
  _objectsMap: {
},
  _objectArraysMap: {
},
  _behaviorNamesMap: {
},
  getObjects: function(objectName) {
    return eventsFunctionContext._objectArraysMap[objectName] || [];
  },
  getObjectsLists: function(objectName) {
    return eventsFunctionContext._objectsMap[objectName] || null;
  },
  getBehaviorName: function(behaviorName) {
    return eventsFunctionContext._behaviorNamesMap[behaviorName] || behaviorName;
  },
  createObject: function(objectName) {
    const objectsList = eventsFunctionContext._objectsMap[objectName];
    if (objectsList) {
      const object = parentEventsFunctionContext ?
        parentEventsFunctionContext.createObject(objectsList.firstKey()) :
        runtimeScene.createObject(objectsList.firstKey());
      if (object) {
        objectsList.get(objectsList.firstKey()).push(object);
        eventsFunctionContext._objectArraysMap[objectName].push(object);
      }
      return object;    }
    return null;
  },
  getInstancesCountOnScene: function(objectName) {
    const objectsList = eventsFunctionContext._objectsMap[objectName];
    let count = 0;
    if (objectsList) {
      for(const objectName in objectsList.items)
        count += parentEventsFunctionContext ?
parentEventsFunctionContext.getInstancesCountOnScene(objectName) :
        runtimeScene.getInstancesCountOnScene(objectName);
    }
    return count;
  },
  getLayer: function(layerName) {
    return runtimeScene.getLayer(layerName);
  },
  getArgument: function(argName) {
if (argName === "id") return id;
    return "";
  },
  getOnceTriggers: function() { return runtimeScene.getOnceTriggers(); }
};


gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__OrderItem.eventsList0(runtimeScene, eventsFunctionContext);

return;
}

gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__OrderItem.registeredGdjsCallbacks = [];
```

Index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <style type="text/css">
        /* Prevent copy paste for all elements except text fields */
        *  { -webkit-user-select:none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); }
        input, textarea  { -webkit-user-select:text; }
        body { background-color:black; color:white }
        
    </style>
    <script src='cordova.js'></script>
        <script src="libs/jshashtable.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="logger.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="gd.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="libs/rbush.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="AsyncTasksManager.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="inputmanager.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="jsonmanager.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="Model3DManager.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="ResourceLoader.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="ResourceCache.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="timemanager.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="polygon.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="runtimeobject.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="profiler.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="RuntimeInstanceContainer.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="runtimescene.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="scenestack.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="force.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="RuntimeLayer.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="layer.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="RuntimeCustomObjectLayer.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="timer.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="runtimewatermark.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="runtimegame.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="variable.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="variablescontainer.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="oncetriggers.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="runtimebehavior.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="spriteruntimeobject.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="affinetransformation.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="CustomRuntimeObjectInstanceContainer.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="CustomRuntimeObject.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="events-tools/commontools.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="events-tools/variabletools.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="events-tools/runtimescenetools.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="events-tools/inputtools.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="events-tools/objecttools.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="events-tools/cameratools.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="events-tools/soundtools.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="events-tools/storagetools.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="events-tools/stringtools.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="events-tools/windowtools.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="events-tools/networktools.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="splash/gd-logo-light.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="pixi-renderers/pixi.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="pixi-renderers/pixi-filters-tools.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="pixi-renderers/runtimegame-pixi-renderer.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="pixi-renderers/runtimescene-pixi-renderer.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="pixi-renderers/layer-pixi-renderer.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="pixi-renderers/pixi-image-manager.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="pixi-renderers/pixi-bitmapfont-manager.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="pixi-renderers/spriteruntimeobject-pixi-renderer.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="pixi-renderers/CustomObjectPixiRenderer.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="pixi-renderers/DebuggerPixiRenderer.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="pixi-renderers/loadingscreen-pixi-renderer.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="pixi-renderers/pixi-effects-manager.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="howler-sound-manager/howler.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="howler-sound-manager/howler-sound-manager.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="fontfaceobserver-font-manager/fontfaceobserver.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="fontfaceobserver-font-manager/fontfaceobserver-font-manager.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="gdjs-evtsext__inapppurchase__finalizeregistration-func.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="gdjs-evtsext__inapppurchase__getproduct-func.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="gdjs-evtsext__inapppurchase__isitemowned-func.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="gdjs-evtsext__inapppurchase__orderitem-func.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="gdjs-evtsext__inapppurchase__registeritem-func.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="gdjs-evtsext__inapppurchase__storeready-func.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="gdjs-evtsext__inapppurchase__watchitemevent-func.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="gdjs-evtsext__panelspritebutton__buttonfsm.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="gdjs-evtsext__panelspritebutton__panelspritebutton.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="Extensions/PanelSpriteObject/panelspriteruntimeobject-pixi-renderer.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="Extensions/PanelSpriteObject/panelspriteruntimeobject.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="Extensions/TextObject/textruntimeobject-pixi-renderer.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="Extensions/TextObject/textruntimeobject.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="Extensions/TweenBehavior/TweenManager.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="Extensions/TweenBehavior/tweenruntimebehavior.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="object-capabilities/AnimatableBehavior.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="object-capabilities/EffectBehavior.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="object-capabilities/FlippableBehavior.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="object-capabilities/OpacityBehavior.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="object-capabilities/ResizableBehavior.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="object-capabilities/ScalableBehavior.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="object-capabilities/TextContainerBehavior.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="code0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="data.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var onDeviceReady=function(){
            //Initialization
            if (typeof navigator !== "undefined" && navigator.splashscreen && navigator.splashscreen.hide)
                navigator.splashscreen.hide();

                //Initialization
                var game = new gdjs.RuntimeGame(gdjs.projectData, {});

                //Create a renderer
                var canvasArea = document.getElementById("canvasArea");
                game.getRenderer().createStandardCanvas(canvasArea);

                //Bind keyboards/mouse/touch events
                game.getRenderer().bindStandardEvents(game.getInputManager(), window, document);

                //Load all assets and start the game
                game.loadAllAssets(function() {
                        game.startGameLoop();
                });
        };
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="canvasArea"></div>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Despite our efforts, it's unclear whether this issue stems from a potential infinite loop or if there's an underlying problem within the plugin integration. Any insights, suggestions, or similar experiences from the community would be immensely appreciated.

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: I can see a lot of times this message, In my opinion is an infinite loop:
00:49.797.667 Default TestMoney (867) com.apple.WebKit ProcessSuspension 0x10f04c460 - [PID=868, throttler=0x10f018880] ProcessThrottler::Activity::Activity: Starting foreground activity / 'WebPageProxy::runJavaScriptInFrameInScriptWorld' 
00:49.925.585 Default TestMoney (867) com.apple.WebKit ProcessSuspension 0x10f04c460 - [PID=868, throttler=0x10f018880] ProcessThrottler::Activity::invalidate: Ending foreground activity / 'WebPageProxy::runJavaScriptInFrameInScriptWorld